# What is the alternative in harmony OS for imageview.setColorFilter in android?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

In android, we can change the color of the drawable by using setColorFilter method. How do we do that in HarmonyOS?

Answer (score 0):

According to the team, HarmonyOS does not support this method by now. Please stay tuned on HarmonyOS official websites.

Answer (score 0):

setColorFilter(Color) is not directly supported in HMOS. But you may check the below callback in ohos.agp.components.element.Element class,

```
public void setColorMatrix​(ColorMatrix matrix)
```

which will also change the color of the element(which is equivalent to drawable in android). Please note, here you need to pass the ColorMatrix object as the argument.
Please check this [documentation](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/element-0000001054358705#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001054358705__setColorMatrix-ohos_agp_render_ColorMatrix-) for more info